# Uploading file to azure blob storage using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, boto3, azure-blob-storage

**I'm trying to upload file to azure blob storage.**

Installed library using following command

```
pip install azure-storage-blob
```

Project is unable to run because of following error

```
[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'app/handler': No module named 'cryptography.hazmat.bindings._padding'
```

Anyone can help to resolve this error. I'm following documentation from following link
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-python

Using Python 3.7

Comment: Did you try `pip install cryptography`?

Comment: Yes its already there

Answer (score 1):

It may be that you have an older version of cryptography, try:

```
pip install --upgrade cryptography
```

It may also be where your code is relative to the cryptography package. Can you code find the package?

Comment: Have you checked  where your code is relative to the cryptography package?

Comment: Just tried on windows system it works, on AWS lambda, I'm packing and shipping the same code, it is throwing this error

Comment: Then it could be a difference in the .net versions in the different environments. Where is your code running?

Comment: Trying to install cryptography from amazon linux, seen that it needs to be complied as per os, code is in python 3.7